# How to add a array to a column of a matrix? (python numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

Like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3,3))
b = np.ones((3,1))
a[:,2] += b
```

expected:

```
a = 
0,0,1
0,0,1
0,0,1
```

in fact:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (3,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,3)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the range of column is required

e.g. `a[:,0:1]` for column 0, `a[:,1:2]` for column 1, and `a[:,2:]` for column 2.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3,3))
b = np.ones((3,1))
a[:,2:] += b
```

output:

> ```
> array([[0., 0., 1.],
>        [0., 0., 1.],
>        [0., 0., 1.]])
> ```